# manipulation of list of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices, generated with the code below

```
a<-c(0,5,0,1,5,1,5,4,6,7)
b<-c(3,1,0,2,4,2,5,5,7,8)
c<-c(5,9,0,1,3,2,5,6,2,7)
d<-c(6,5,0,1,3,4,5,6,7,1)
k<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
k<-as.matrix(k)
#dimnames(k)<-list(cntry,cntry)

e<-c(0,5,2,2,1,2,3,6,9,2)
f<-c(2,0,4,1,1,3,4,5,1,4)
g<-c(3,3,0,2,0,9,3,2,1,9)
h<-c(6,1,1,1,5,7,8,8,0,2)
l<-data.frame(e,f,g,h)
l<-as.matrix(l)
#dimnames(l)<-list(cntry,cntry)

list<-list(k,l)
names(list)<-2010:2011
list

list
$`2010`
      a b c d
 [1,] 0 3 5 6
 [2,] 5 1 9 5
 [3,] 0 3 2 2
 [4,] 1 2 1 1
 [5,] 5 4 3 3
 [6,] 1 2 2 4
 [7,] 5 5 5 5
 [8,] 4 5 6 6
 [9,] 6 7 2 7
[10,] 7 8 7 1

$`2011`
      e f g h
 [1,] 0 2 3 6
 [2,] 5 0 3 1
 [3,] 2 4 0 1
 [4,] 2 1 2 1
 [5,] 1 1 0 5
 [6,] 2 3 9 7
 [7,] 3 4 3 8
 [8,] 6 5 2 8
 [9,] 9 1 1 0
[10,] 2 4 9 2
```

In each matrix I would like to delete the rows that are smaller than 1. But when I delete in matrix "2010" the first row (because <1), all other first rows in 2010 and 2011 should be deleted. Then the third row of first column is <1, then all other third columns should be deleted and so on...

The result should look like:

```
      a b c d
 [4,] 1 2 1 1
 [6,] 1 2 2 4
 [7,] 5 5 5 5
 [8,] 4 5 6 6
[10,] 7 8 7 1

$`2011`
      e f g h
 [4,] 2 1 2 1
 [6,] 2 3 9 7
 [7,] 3 4 3 8
 [8,] 6 5 2 8
[10,] 2 4 9 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[!rowSums(x <1),])
```

If we need to remove the rows that are common

```
ind <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(list, function(x) !rowSums(x < 1)))
lapply(list, function(x) x[ind,])
#      a b c d
#[1,] 1 2 1 1
#[2,] 1 2 2 4
#[3,] 5 5 5 5
#[4,] 4 5 6 6
#[5,] 7 8 7 1

#$`2011`
#     e f g h
#[1,] 2 1 2 1
#[2,] 2 3 9 7
#[3,] 3 4 3 8
#[4,] 6 5 2 8
#[5,] 2 4 9 2
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments about removing rows where the row is greater than the standard deviation of each columns,

```
lapply(list, function(x) {
       for(i in seq_len(ncol(x))) x <- x[!rowSums(x > sd(x[,i])),]
         x 
   })
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. Great help

Comment: Thanks akrun. I have updated the question, that's why I haven't accepted any answer yet. I will appreciate for any feedback.

Comment: any idea how to tackle the below  problem?If we consider the original list of matrices: How could I delete the rows which are larger than the standard deviation(std) of columns? So it should be as follows:

i) start with the first column of the first matrix ii) calculate its std ii) delete the rows of each matrices larger than the std of the first column of the first matrix iii) proceed to second column of the first matrix, etc...

Comment: @SarpKayaAcar  I updated based on the comments.  Check if that is wha tyou wanted

Comment: I get a dimension error   Error in x[, i] : incorrect number of  Dimensions Called from: is.data.frame(x)

Comment: @SarpKayaAcar  Could you please update your post with the expected output because based on your description,all the rows are delted after assigning based on each column's standard deviation

Comment: Ok the example was not suitable for the code. I have applied it to a long time series and it works as expected. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 1):

```
# get union of the row index with at least one of the elements less 1 
removed <- Reduce(union, lapply(list, function(x) which(rowSums(x < 1) != 0)))
lapply(list, function(x) x[-removed, ])

$`2010`
     a b c d
[1,] 1 2 1 1
[2,] 1 2 2 4
[3,] 5 5 5 5
[4,] 4 5 6 6
[5,] 7 8 7 1

$`2011`
     e f g h
[1,] 2 1 2 1
[2,] 2 3 9 7
[3,] 3 4 3 8
[4,] 6 5 2 8
[5,] 2 4 9 2
```